# Genitiv von Namen mit Adelsprädikat

Tags: genitive, person-names

Bildunterschrift in der Sächsischen Zeitung vom 28.01.19, Seite 3:

> Das Wappen **derer** von Zimmermann, de**n** Besitzer**n** bis 1945

1. Gibt es Verweise in Grammatiken/Regelwerken auf diese Art der Genitivkonstruktion bei Adelstiteln? Klingt in meinen Ohren etwas gestelzt (es handelt sich um einen längeren, neutral und sachlich abgefassten Zeitungsartikel).
2. Warum wird danach in den Dativ gewechselt? Die Formulierung **das Wappen von den Besitzern* ist ja wohl eher umgangssprachlich und nicht in einem Zeitungsartikel zu erwarten.

Ich hätte einfach geschrieben:

> *Das Wappen der von Zimmermanns, der Besitzer bis 1945*.

Ist das falsch?

Comment: Hat mit Adelstitel wenih zu tun: "Das Begehren derer Hinterbliebenen, den wenigen gemeldeten", wäre deckungsgleich. Ja, kann auch einfacher geschrieben werden. Bei Titeln ist es formulaisch, sonst archaisch, obsolet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Der erste Punkt berührt eine politische Frage. Eigentlich sind Adelstitel abgeschafft, *von Zimmermann* ist ein Name. Im Nominativ kann man dann *die von Zimmermanns* benutzen, wie man auch *die Kohls: Ein Familiendrama* schreiben kann, oder, im Genitiv, *das Familiendrama der Kohls*, *das Wappen der von Zimmermanns*.

Aber wenn man am Adel festhält, sieht man eine Kombination aus *von* plus Name. Im Beispiel

> das Wappen derer von Zimmermann

hängt der Name *Zimmermann* von der Präposition *von* ab, und diese steht zu einem Pronomen (nicht zu einem Artikel). Daher die "verstärkte" Form *derer*.

Der zweite Punkt ist einfach: Die Kasuskongruenz in der Apposition wackelt. In der Duden-Grammatik (8. Auflage) heißt es dazu:

> In bestimmten Konfigurationen besteht die Tendenz, den Dativ als "Normalkasus" zu wählen [...] Der Dativ gilt in all diesen Fällen als nicht korrekt. (§ 1553)

Das "nicht korrekt" finde ich streng, dafür ist der Dativ meines Erachtens inzwischen zu weit verbreitet.

Zur Lektüre konnte ich finden: Jost Gippert, "Zur Dativ-Apposition im Deutschen" (1981) ([Link](http://titus.fkidg1.uni-frankfurt.de/personal/jg/pdf/jg1981.pdf)). Dort wird festgestellt, daß nichtkongruente appositive Dative meist zu Genitiven und von Präpositionen regierten Akkusativen stehen. Die Konstruktion ist in Zeitungen und Zeitschriften so verbreitet, daß Gippert zu dem Schluß kommt, daß die Dativapposition bei einigen Sprechern zur Normalform geworden sei.

Comment: Das Experiment, ein rückverbürgerlichtes ***die von Zimmermanns*** und ein adelstraditionelles ***derer von Zimmermann*** gegenüberzustellen, beschreibt allerdings einen recht speziellen Fall, nämlich denjenigen spät nachgeadelter Bürgerlicher (hier: Familie Zimmermann). Ursprünglich bezog sich das "von" ja auf einen Ort, z.B. den Ort mit dem Stammsitz (und ggf. Burg oder Schloss) der Familie. Bei solchen Familien heißt es üblicherweise nach wie vor ***derer von Hohenzollern***. Höchstens ironisch (oder aggressiv egalitaristisch) könnte man sagen ***die von Hohenzollerns*** (?).

Comment: Man kann natürlich immer *des Hauses Hohenzollern* sagen, damit man es nicht wie einen Nachnamen behandeln muß. – Von denen sind einige jetzt wohl Potsdamer ([Link](https://www.pnn.de/potsdam/neubuerger-die-von-preussens-sind-jetzt-potsdamer/21292610.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Ohne jetzt eine Quelle zu haben, ist das aus meiner Sicht einfach eine Frage von Singular oder Plural.

*Derer von Zimmermann* bezieht sich auf mehrere Personen aus dem Geschlecht der Familie von Zimmermann. *Der von Zimmermann* bezieht sich auf eine bestimmte Frau aus dem Geschlecht der Familie von Zimmermann.

Und es ist einfach auch eine veraltete Form.

Comment: Singular vs Plural ist nicht die Frage, es geht doch nur um die Mehrzahl (_die von Zimmermanns_) hier